# JIRA - "Done" issues marked as "Unresolved"

Tags: jira

I'm a bit of a novice using JIRA and I don't know why this is happening. Lately, whenever I mark an issue as "Done", the system won't update as it being "Closed" but rather keep them as "Unresolved". Why would this happen? I don't know what information I must provide to solve this issue, except that I'm using JIRA 6.1.3, self-hosted, and no extra plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That issue is neither fully resolved nor necessarily related, but you might want to check into [Fix apparent data integrity violation with closed issues not actually being closed (JRA-34222)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34222), in particular [Andreas Knecht's comment](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34222?focusedCommentId=505081&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-505081), summarizing potential race conditions during workflow changes:

> Yeah so bulk editing while doing workflow changes definitely has the potential to cause this sort of a problem. JIRA doesn't really lock down a project while doing workflow migrations AFAIK so this kind of thing can always happen if concurrent operations are happening during a migration.
>
> It's a complicated problem with an even more complicated solution. For some reading on an analysis we did ages ago see [not accessible link to 'Concurrency+Problems+in+JIRA']. Also [not accessible link to 'Concurrency+bug']. It's a known problem, but the solution has huge performance implications for JIRA and will take considerable effort to implement and test.

The last [comment from a Cisco employee](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34222?focusedCommentId=522890&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-522890) seems to confirm Andreas' summary that this might be a generally applicable issue with JIRA for the time being:

> JIRA 5.2.8 we have been having an issue like this for months. I can
>   not view it, but see also: JSP-161469
>
> Recent investigation has correlated "Tried to reopen the IndexReader,
>   but it threw AlreadyClosedException." message as closely following the
>   execution of Jython scripts. [...]

### Possible Remedy/Workaround

While not addressing the root cause, you an see from the [screenshot attached by Michael Knight](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/attachment/98781/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-09%20at%2014.36.47%20.png) that Atlassian seems to have been able to fix the integrity issue at hand by [Using the Database Integrity Checker](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+the+Database+Integrity+Checker):

[image]

This aptly named JIRA feature is *useful in a number of situations, e.g.*

> - **Before migrating a project to a new workflow** *[emphasis mine]*
> - An external program is modifying JIRA's database
> - Troubleshooting a server crash

Using such a tool is obviously not without risks itself, so please note that Atlassian *strongly recommend[s] taking a backup of your data before correcting any data inconsistencies* accordingly

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing this after reading your post, but the issues are still unresolved. Moreover, I tried reindexing and it still didn't work. What are your suggestions about dealing with this kind of problem if I cannot resolve it accordingly? Do I just ignore that?

Comment: Sorry to hear - I'd engage directly with [Atlassian support](https://support.atlassian.com/customer/home) (you need to log in to create a support ticket) for this, they might have many more rare but similar issues on file already and be able to identify your particular one accordingly.

Comment: As mentioned in this page this INTEGRITY CHECKER is not availabe for  JIRA CLOUD - https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.botronsoft.jira.rollout.integrity-check - How can I solve this problem ? with a bulk edit ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good confluence answer that explains why this happens and a few workarounds [Confluence Answer to Done issues as Unresolved](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Closed+Issues+Showing+as+UNRESOLVED+or+Open+Issues+appears+as+Resolved+with+Strike+Through)